# Proving a propositional stament about infinity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

This question is from Kenneth.H.Rosen's Discrete Mathematics.
The problem statement is as follows-

1. Show that if the statement P(n) is true for infintetly many positive integers n, and P(n+1) implies P(n) is true for all positive integers n , then show that P(n) is true for all positive integers n.

What I was thinking, that consider a fixed integer say k , such that P(k) is true, and with a simple induction one can prove that P(i) is true for all i<=k , this is good enough and formal till now. Now, Intuitively, since k can become "large enough" , hence we can say that P(n) is true for all integers n. However, I am quite sceptical about this, how can we formally say , that P(n) is true just because there are infinitely many numbers k such that P(k) is true.

Any  help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Suppose you want to derive $P(m)$ for an arbitrary $m$. Your first argument shows that you just need $P(k)$ for $m \leq k$. You have been given an infinite list of (presumably distinct) $n$ for which $P(n)$ holds, so you can just look for a number bigger than $m$ on that list, _as long as you're sure you'll find one after finitely many steps_. So, consider how you'd argue that you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exists $N$ such that, for any $n >N$, $P(n)$ is false. This implies that the set for which $P(n)$ is true is finite (try to prove this formally). So the set of positive integers for which $P(n)$ is true has no maximum.

We know that there is at least one $k$ for which $P(k)$ is true, so in particular $P(1)$ is true (or $P(0)$ depending on your definition of positive integers).

Suppose $P(n)$ is true. Because it can't be the maximum $n$ for which $P(n)$ is true, we know that there exists $n_2>n$ such that $P(n_2)$ is true. This implies that $P(n+1)$ is true.

So $P(n)$ is true for all the positive integers by induction.

Comment: I didn't get the last argument, "we know that there exists n2>n such that P(n2) is true" how does this imply that n2 must be n+1 only, or why P(n+1) must be true?

Comment: @green_32 by induction if $P(n_2)$ is true, $P(k)$ is true for any $k \le n_2$. In particular, because $n+1 \le n_2$ $P(n+1)$ is true

Answer (score 4):

**For the sake of variety, I offer a proof by contradiction**:

$1.$ Suppose $P(n+1)$ implies $P(n)$ for every positive integer $n$. Furthermore, suppose $P(n)$ is true for infinitely many positive integers. In other words, let $S$ be an infinite set such that $S = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : P(n)\}$.

$2.$ Now, assume $P(n)$ is *not* true for every positive integer. In other words, assume there exists at least one positive integer $n$ such that $\neg P(n)$. From here on, let $a$ be any arbitrary positive integer such that $\neg P(a)$.

$3.$ Assuming $\neg P(a)$, consider that $\neg P(n)$ for every integer $n > a$. For if there was an integer $b > a$ such that $P(b)$, then by induction we would have $P(n)$ for every positive integer $n \le b$, which would imply $P(a)$ and lead to a contradiction.

$4.$ Hence, for every positive integer $n$, if $P(n)$ is true, then $1 \le n < a$. By definition, $S$ contains every positive integer $n$ for which $P(n)$ is true. Thus, for every $n \in S$, we must have $1 \le n < a$. This implies $|S| < a$, which contradicts the premise stating $S$ is an infinite set.

$5.$ Therefore, if $P(n+1)$ implies $P(n)$ for every positive integer $n$ and $P(n)$ is true for infinitely many positive integers, then there *cannot* exist a positive integer $n$ such that $\neg P(n)$. In other words, it must be the case that $P(n)$ is true for every positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q(n)=\neg P(n)$ and assume $Q(n_0)$ is true for some positive integer $n_0$. Considering the contrapositive of $P(n+1) \implies P(n)$, we get the standard induction step $Q(n) \implies Q(n+1)$, which implies $Q(n)$ is true for all $n \geq n_0$. Therefore $P(n)$ is true for only finitely many values $( <n_0)$, which contradicts our initial assumption. As a result $Q(n)$ must be false for all positive integers $n$, or in other words $P(n)$ must be true for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers are pointing out the imprecision in the original question. There are two main ways to **state** "infinitely many naturals (or positive integers) satisfy P", and each has its own advantages (independent of this question):

1. `∀k∈ℕ ∃m∈ℕ ( k < m ∧ P(m) ).`
   [For every k∈ℕ, P is satisfied by some m > k.]
2. `∃f∈ℕ→ℕ ( ∀i,j∈ℕ ( f(i) ≠ f(j) ) ∧ ∀i∈ℕ ( P(f(i)) )`.
   [There is an injective function from ℕ to natural numbers satisfying P.]

(If you want to state it for "positive integers" rather than "naturals", just change "ℕ" to "ℕ<sup>+</sup>".)

The advantage of (1) is that it does **not** require reasoning about functions or sets at all:

```
∀k∈ℕ ( P(k+1) ⇒ P(k) ).  [Premise 1]
∀k∈ℕ ∃m∈ℕ ( k < m ∧ P(m) ).  [Premise 2]
Given any k∈ℕ such that P(k):
  Let m∈ℕ such that k < m ∧ P(m).
  P(m−0) ∨ m−0∉ℕ.
  Given any d∈ℕ such that P(m−d) ∨ m−d∉ℕ:
    If P(m−d):
      If m−(d+1)∈ℕ:
        P(m−(d+1)).  [by Premise 1]
      P(m−(d+1)) ∨ m−(d+1)∉ℕ.
    If m−d∉ℕ:
      m−(d+1)∉ℕ.
      P(m−(d+1)) ∨ m−(d+1)∉ℕ.
    P(m−(d+1)) ∨ m−(d+1)∉ℕ.
  Therefore ∀d∈ℕ ( P(m−d) ∨ m−d∉ℕ ).  [by induction]
  m−k∈ℕ.  [since k < m]
  Thus P(m−(m−k)) ∨ m−(m−k)∉ℕ.
  But m−(m−k) = k ∈ ℕ.
  Therefore P(m−(m−k)).
  P(k).
∀k∈ℕ ( P(k) ).
```

It needs more work if you use the second definition of "infinitely many". You would essentially need yet another induction to obtain the first definition from the second one. Let me know if you are interested.